# How can you play a recorded audio blob on the client side using howler.js?

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-recording, howler.js, bloburls

The purpose is to record an audio file on the client and play it using the blob URL without using an HTTP GET.

The logic I have looks something like this:

```
var blob = "blob:null/5fa0fa6d-0b2a-4be6-a762-c81e4bf88f0d";
var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL ).createObjectURL(blob);
var sound = new Howl({
  src: [url]
});
sound.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use URLs or base64 data URIs in Howl's src.
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#options

and I created example using base64 src.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nylkdl?file=index.js

cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second link has really clean code.